# Creating address for streets based on direction and hierarchy of streets using ArcMap, QGIS or python?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap

I have a street layer with the correct direction for each line. I want to make a geocoding address based on the direction of lines and hierarchy (highway, main way, alley, etc). For example, in alley 1 i want to create a text like ( alley 1, main street 2, highway 4).Because of line 3 is an alley, this line not included in the address. I want to create this for all of the street lines in a city.

I try to use  [Feature vertices to point tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) Compute start and end points of lines, then join the results and find the hierarchies, but sometimes it did not work.

Is there any ArcMap, Qgis or python solution for my issue?

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between 3 and 4? Why 3 is not in result text?

Comment: Not sure how you code your hierarchy in the attribute table, but this is a workflow I would try: (1) Fetch the *start point* of each alley, (2) Find the *main street* which is determined by *touches()* with the *start point*, (3) Repeat *(1)* and *(2)* between *main street* and *highway* as well, (4) Concatenate these fields.

Comment: @Kazuhito. what is touches()? Is it a function in arcpy ? or touche by boundary in select by attribute?

Comment: I have a column in the attribute table named typeStreet. In this column, i can find street type ( mainstreet, alley etc)

Comment: Sorry, *touches()* was QGIS matching expression in the spatial join. Perhaps similar to ArcGIS' *Boundary_touches*... not so sure about it.

Comment: @Kazuhito Thanks. I'll try it

Comment: My apologies - my earlier suggestion seems inefficient. New expression `overlay_touches()` will make it much simpler. I will post an idea based on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small example to mimic your case. I have named the layer as 'streets'.

[image]

I am using QGIS 3.16.3, which is equiped with `overlay_touches()` expression in the Field Calculator.

The script is:

```
if("typeStreet" = 'main street', 
   concat('Alley ', 
          array_to_string(overlay_touches('streets', name, filter:= typeStreet = 'alley')), 
          ', Main street ', 
          "name", 
          ', Highway ',  
          array_to_string(overlay_touches('streets', name, filter:= typeStreet = 'highway'))  
         ) , 
   NULL)
```

Important part of the script is `overlay_touches('streets', name, filter:= typeStreet = 'alley')`, which will extract "name" attribute from the 'streets' layer (i.e. own layer) and filter it by the *typeStreet*. If it is 'alley', it selects the feature fid.1, and 'highway' will be fid.4.

[Logic behind the script]

In this calculation, `Main street` acts as a hub for the whole `alley - main street - highway` network. It enables determination of the `touching`(allay <- main street -> highway) by single command `overlay_touches()` then use `filter` to switch between alley/highway. So the calculation starts only if the `typeStreet` is `main street`, and ignore other records.

[image]

Output will be something like below.

[image]